# scala.MatchError with java.sql.TimeStamp

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I'm getting the below exception when I try to read data from CSV file, construct dataframe and load the records into a table. What is the root cause for the exception?

```
 scala.MatchError: 2018-08-17 23:10:16.694 (of class java.sql.Timestamp)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
```

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` type is `Long` so it doesn't match with data `2018-08-17 23:10:16.694` which is `String`.